# Can we refresh the access token in Power bi which is sent by Azure using React app.?

Tags: reactjs, azure, powerbi, azure-active-directory, powerbi-rest-api

I'm using powerbi-client-react npm package for my project. When I sign in in the report the azure sends an access token passing token and embed URL, I'm accessing the power bi report via React. The issue is azure token gets expired in 1hour. Can I refresh the access token sent by Azure for power bi report in react. Can we refresh the access token directly from react app?

```
    <PowerBIEmbed
      embedConfig = {{
        type: 'report',
        id: '<report Id>',
        accessToken: '<access token>',
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
        permissions: models.Permissions.All,
        viewMode: models.ViewMode.Edit,
        // eventHooks: {
        //   accessTokenProvider : getNewAccessToken
        // },
        settings: {
          // filterPaneEnabled: false,
          panes: {
            filters: {
              expanded: false,
              visible: true
            },
            bookmarks: {
              visible: false
            },
            fields: {
              expanded: false
            },
            pageNavigation: {
              visible: true
            },
            selection: {
              visible: false
            },
            syncSlicers: {
              visible: false
            },
            visualizations: {
              expanded: false
            }
          },
          // background: models.BackgroundType.Transparent,
        }
          }}

      eventHandlers ={
        new Map([
            ['loaded', function () {
                console.log('Report loaded');
            }],
            ['rendered', function () {
                console.log('Report rendered');
            }],
            ['error', function (event) {
                console.log(event.detail);
            }]
        ])
      }
    cssClassName = { "Embed-container" }

  getEmbeddedComponent = {getEmbeddedComponent()}

  getEmbeddedComponent = { (embeddedReport) => {
        window.report = embeddedReport;
     }}
  />
```

Comment: In the permission, you need to pass offline_access to get the refresh token along with access token.

Comment: I'm somehow having difficulty passing access token in a variable and assigned it to accessToken attribute in embedConfig. If I pass that same access token as a string between quotes, my report renders otherwise it doesn't. Any advice please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment (Postman) and got the results successfully like below:***

I generated **tokens for PowerBi** by using the below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:*****
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default offline_access
redirect_uri:redirect_uri
code:code
```

[image]

**To refresh the access token, I used the below parameters:**

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:****
grant_type:refresh_token
refresh_token: refresh_token
```

[image]

To refresh the access token in your React App, try the below sample code:

```js
let config = {
        type: 'report',
        tokenType: models.TokenType.Aad,
        accessToken: “***** …”,
        embedUrl: “https: …”,
        eventHooks: {
            accessTokenProvider: getNewAccessToken
        }
    };
let embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];
report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);
```

To know more in detail, **refer** the below MsDoc:

[Refresh the access token in Power BI embedded analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/refresh-token)

Answer (score 0):

the important thing is **offline_access**, it will give **refresh_token**

> scope:https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default **offline_access**

refer to here https://learn.microsoft.com/EN-US/azure/active-directory/develop/scopes-oidc

[image]